# How to check integration history of a Cl

Tags: perforce-integrate

how to check if any changelist of project A is integrated in project B? and also to get corresponding submitted Cl in project B. Please share any perforce command

Answer (score 2):

It's worth pointing out the unit of integration in P4 is files, not changelists, so the `p4` commands are mostly focused around telling you which files are integrated or not. You can, however, find out which changelists still have some files that need to be integrated - use the `p4 interchanges` command. The [Perforce docs](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r13.1/manuals/cmdref/interchanges.html) explain the syntax.

Assuming that you have a branch spec that describes the relationship of `project A` and `project B` called `projAprojB`, then you can get the outstanding changelists with:

```
p4 interchanges -b projAprojB
```

You can also get a similar view of outstanding changes in the P4V Merge/Integrate dialog box.

Alternatively, you can use the 'revision graph' in P4V to see the integrations performed on a given file; doing this on a file from the changelist you want to know about will give you the information to work out if it has been integrated into the other project and the changelist for that was.

If this doesn't suit your needs then your only option is to write a script, either with shell scripting using `p4` or one of the [APIs provided by Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/tools-apis)

Comment: i have tried revision graph...i want command to check any particular revision of a file in project A is integrated in which CL of project B. I have tried "p4 integrated" command  also..but using this command for each file of Cl is making it very complex.